# PHP private property should not be accessible in Child class

Tags: php

I have one silly doubts.
I'm  setting username property as private in user class
But According to the rules private property should not be accessible
in Child class or inherited and outside of the class but it's happening
in my code. I just want to know where i did wrong.

```
<?php
    class User{
        private $username;
    }
  class UserRepository extends User{
        public function get(){
            return  $this->username;
           //this should give error can't access private property
        }
        public function set($username){
         $this->username=$username; 
         //this should give error can't access private property
        }
    }

    $UserReposetry =new UserRepository;
    $UserReposetry->username='daulat';//this should give error.
    echo $UserReposetry->username;//this should give error.
```

It should not work but it's working.

Comment: Yeah, that's PHP. In fact you are not accessing the private `$username` of class `User`, but a new `public` (since not specified) `$username` property you created by assigning the value 'daulat'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way,
Here see the code and see result (error)

```
<?php
class User{
    private $username="aaa";
}
class UserRepository extends User{
    public function get(){
        return  $this->username;
    }

}
$UserReposetry =new UserRepository;
echo $UserReposetry->get();//this should give error.
```

**Output:** 
**Notice:** Undefined property: `UserRepository::$username` in C:\Users...........index.php on line 7
(To see this notice you have to set your error reporting as E_ALL)

And line 7 means `return  $this->username;` , try using ::parent keyword too

In Your Code: You are just setting a new variable. So don't misunderstand that code is using private member.

Comment: enable error reporting on in you php.ini file or use php code to enable error reporting. You will get the same error msg that I am getting. Use this code not yours, because you are just creating a variable. TO understand run this code. TO see the error put `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` on your php file

Comment: Enable error reporting .. For User class it's giving error 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property User::$username in /var/www/test.com/public_html/demo/index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/test.com/public_html/demo/index.php on line 15